# Using a .sub file to run a batch file multiple times. I want to create new directories each time

Tags: python, batch-file

Here's my .sub file

```
#submit.sub
Executable = random.bat
transfer_input_files = random_number.py
output = random_number.out 
log  =  random_number.log     
error  =  random_number.err 
queue 10
```

and here's the random.bat file I want to run:

```
python random_number.py >> Output.txt
```

So at the moment my submission file runs successfully, but the Output.txt is overwritten for each job in the queue. Instead I wish to write somewhere to create a new sub folder or preferably rename the Output to Output1.txt, Output2.txt etc so that if I write queue 10 I end up with 10 files with the 10 results in from each job. Anyone good with command prompt/batch files and could help?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not important for the numbers to be in sequence use `%random%`:

```
python random_number.py >> Output%random%.txt
```

Otherwise look into the documentation of your launcher: maybe there's a "job number" parameter you can add to the command line and reuse it in the batch file.